# Share explorer is Not opening in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco

I have installed alfresco-5 on ubuntu with mysql-connector. I am able to open the alfresco explorer but when I click on Alfresco Share, the explorer doesn't respond any thing. please help

Comment: Could you please add a log, or be more specific about the issue ?

Comment: thanx for reply, when I am accessing with full url like localhost:8080/share then it's able to access but when I am clicking on share url nothing happened.

Comment: Do you have some logs ? Do your share application is accessible from its url ? http://localhost:8080/share

Comment: can you please tell me how I can see log? yes I am able to access by direct url( localhost:8080/share)

Comment: Have you changed theses parameters in alfresco-global.properties ? #share.context=share
#share.host=${localname}
#share.port=8080
#share.protocol=http